# Find The Equation of the plane in $R^3$ known two points p1 , p2 on the plane and the distance between the plane and a third given point p3 is d

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

Assume $p1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ , $p2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $p3=(x_3,y_3,z_3)$

**THIS IS HOW I IMAGINE IT** (so it may be wrong)

[image]

$p_1p_2^\rightarrow =(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$ which is a vector on the plane

i tried to get the projection vector of $p_1p_3^\rightarrow$
 onto $p_1p_2^\rightarrow$ then the rejection Which as i think so is the normal vector $n^\rightarrow$ according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection

states that the vector rejection is the orthogonal projection of $p_1p_3^\rightarrow$ onto the plane

vector projection of $p_1p_3^\rightarrow$ onto $p_1p_2^\rightarrow =$ $\frac{p_1p_3^\rightarrow.p_1p_2^\rightarrow}{\lVert p_1p_2^\rightarrow\rVert^2}p_1p_2^\rightarrow=v^\rightarrow$

then the Vector rejection which is the normal vector $n^\rightarrow$ =$p_1p_3^\rightarrow - v^\rightarrow$

then the equation of the plane is $$n^\rightarrow.((x,y,z)-(x_1,y_1,z_1))=0$$

i don't know if this is right or wrong because as you see i didn't use the distance he gave and i searched a lot but i found nothing

so i need any clarification please

Comment: There is an infinite number of planes that contain the line through $p_1$ and $p_2$. The distance from $p_3$ to this line is equal to the distance from $p_3$ to only one of these planes; for the rest, the distance is less than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling $p^*$ the tangent point between the plane and the sphere $||p-p_3||= d$, we have the relations

$$
\cases{
||p^*-p_3||^2=d^2\\
(p^*-p_3)\cdot(p_1-p_2) = 0\\
(p^*-p_3)\cdot(p_1-p^*) = 0
}
$$

We have three conditions and three unknowns which are the $p^*$ components.

Case study

$$
\cases{
p_1 = (1,0,1)\\
p_2 = (2,-1,0)\\
p_3 = (-2,1,-2)\\
d = 2
}
$$

$$
p^* = \left(-\frac{2}{7} \left(5+\sqrt{11}\right),-\frac{3}{7} \left(\sqrt{11}-2\right),\frac{1}{7}
   \left(\sqrt{11}-9\right)\right)
$$

and the plane equation is

$$
(p-p^*)\cdot(p^*-p_3)=0,\ \ \ p=(x,y,z)
$$
[image]

Comment: omg 
thank you so much